# How to save Data in Related Models in Asp.net core web API using EF core?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I am having problem saving data into related model in asp.net core web API and EF core and DTO.
I have a product model and category model, one category can have many products but one product can only belong to one category.

```
 public class Product
    {
        [Key]
        [Required]
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public Double Price { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public Category Category { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Desc { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Absolute_Url { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTime PostDate { get; set; }
    }
```

```
public class Category
    {
        [Key]
        [Required]
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string? Name { get; set; }

        
    }
```

I have a Product DTO model

```
public class ProductDTO
    {
        [Required]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public Double Price { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Desc { get; set; }

        
    }
```

My logic is, when I post data using Product DTO model, I Use posted CategoryId to get the category then update Product Model before saving it.
After I save, Category is null in the product model, as show below.

```
[
  {
    "productId": 3,
    "title": "Swagger Test",
    "price": 20,
    "category": null,
    "desc": "Swagger Test",
    "absolute_Url": "Christian/Swagger Test",
    "postDate": "2022-07-15T13:18:42.0060792"
  }
]
```

Here is my controller method

```
[HttpPost("Create")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Create([FromBody] ProductDTO productDTO)
        {
            if (productDTO == null)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            try
            {
                //get product category
                var category = await _uow.Category.FindById(productDTO.CategoryId);

                if(category == null)
                {
                    return BadRequest();
                }
                var product = _mapper.Map<Product>(productDTO);

                product.Category = category;
                product.PostDate = DateTime.Now;
                product.Absolute_Url = $"{category.Name}/{product.Title}";

               
                _uow.Product.Create(product);
                await _uow.Save();
                return Ok();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

        }
```

Kindly help

Comment: Is the `categoryId` set in the database?

Comment: Product Model has a CategoryId column in the database after adding migrations and updating the database

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify, is there a value in the `CategoryId` column for the product you posted?

Comment: Yes, there is a value, of an already existing category in the database

Comment: When retrieveing the value, i quess in your case something like `_uow.FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.ProductId == productId)`, instead try this: `_uow.Where(p => p.ProductId == productId).Include(p => p.Category).FirstOrDefautlAsync()`

Comment: I dont think that is issue, I am get the category,` //get product category
                var category = await _uow.Category.FindById(productDTO.CategoryId);`

Comment: Can you post the code of the method used to retrieve a product?

Comment: ` var products = await _uow.Product.FindAll();
                return Ok(products); `

Comment: I really would advise you to check out the documentation on [Eager Loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager), you say it is not the issue but you are not including anything

Comment: Actually you are correct, the problem was that I was not including Eager Loading. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

So If I understand the question correctly, you can do something like this:

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Double Price { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Desc { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Absolute_Url { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime PostDate { get; set; }
}
```

So notice how Ive just added Category Id and then added virtual to your category entity. So EF Core, in my experience, will now know relate your Category ID to your Category Entity. So no need to search for that ID in the category db, just save your Product with the category ID.

When you pull that entity out of the database now, it will pull the category Entity out with it if you tell you Response DTO to include CategoryDTO `public CategoryDto Category { get; set; }`

Comment: There is still a need to lookup the `Category`, especially because the DTO doesn't have the `Category` property and a mapper is being used to translate from DTO to Model. I do agree that it is helpful to include the FKs (`CategoryId`) in the Model but it is not strictly necessary.